# glob.glob("**/*.jpg") as an itertator or lazy load?

Tags: python

I want to know if is possible to use `glob.glob("**/*.jpg")` in order to get all images in several folders but as an iterator in order to avoid filling the memory

Currently, I am using the following code with glob:

```
for file in glob.glob("**/*.jpg")[:1]:
    print(file)
```

but I use

```
for model_folder in os.scandir(folder):
    for model_folder_content in os.scandir(model_folder):
        print(model_folder_content)
```

The problem with the first approach is that if there are a lot of files that can fill the memory and fails, so the idea is to use scandir because return an iterator, but with the option of using a pattern.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Good solutions below, but at the risk of stating the obvious, be aware that by reading the directories lazily, you can get inconsistent results if the directories change before the iterator is exhausted, including missing or duplicate filenames.

Comment: thanks @sj95126, the directory is a only read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [glob.iglob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob):

> ```
> glob.iglob(pathname, *, recursive=False)
>
> Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without actually
> storing them all simultaneously.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pathlib.Path.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob), which returns a `generator`:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> folder = Path('/home/accdias')
>>> jpgs = folder.rglob('*.jpg')
>>> type(jpgs)
<class 'generator'>
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The glob module has a dedicated method for this particular problem called `iglob()` which takes the same parameters as `glob()` and returns an iterator instead of a list.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) for `iglob` state the following:

> Return an iterator which yields the same values as glob() without
> actually storing them all simultaneously.

In your case, the code snippet could look something like:

```
for file in glob.iglob("**/*.jpg"):
    # do something with the file
```